# Error in match.arg(method), where it comes from?

Tags: r

I am running this code in order to get a bound test on stock datas.
Everything is working until I made my `ardlBoundOrders` and get the following error : `Error in match.arg(method) : 'arg' must be of length 1`

Where this error comes from ? Is that possible this comes from the merged dataset (since I run the code without any problem when I only use excel imported dataset) ? How to fix it ?

Thanks for your help!

Here is the script :

```
library(quantmod)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dLagM)

tickers = c("DIS", "GILD", "AMZN", "AAPL")
stocks<-getSymbols(tickers,
                   from = "1994-01-01",
                   to = "2022-02-01",
                   periodicity = "monthly",
                   src = "yahoo")

DISclose<-DIS[, 4:4]
GILDclose<-GILD[, 4:4]
AMZNclose<-AMZN[, 4:4]
AAPLclose<-AAPL[, 4:4]


newdata <- merge(DATA, DISclose)


formula <- DIS.Close ~ USDEUR+CPI+CONSCONF+FEDFUNDS+HOUST+UNRATE+INDPRO+VIX+SPY+CLI
ARDLfit <- ardlDlm(formula = formula, data = newdata, p = 10, q = 10)
summary(ARDLfit)

orders3 <- ardlBoundOrders(data = newdata, formula =
                             formula, ic = "BIC", max.p = 2, max.q = 2)
p <- data.frame(orders3$q, orders3$p) + 1
Boundtest<- ardlBound(data = DATA, formula =
                        formula2, p=p , ECM = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
disney<-Boundtest[["ECM"]][["EC.t"]]
plot(disney, type="l")
```

Update :

I think I found something :

When I merge my datas, it square them by allocating each of the stocks data on each of my rows datas. An example would be more explicit :

Here is the variable DATA :

```
> DATA
# A tibble: 337 × 12
   Date                  VIX USDEUR   CPI CONSCONF FEDFUNDS HOUST   SPY INDPRO UNRATE
   <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1994-01-01 00:00:00  10.6  0.897  146.     101.     3.05  1272  28.8   67.1    6.6
 2 1994-02-01 00:00:00  14.9  0.895  147.     101.     3.25  1337  28.0   67.1    6.6
 3 1994-03-01 00:00:00  20.5  0.876  147.     101.     3.34  1564  26.7   67.8    6.5
 4 1994-04-01 00:00:00  13.8  0.877  147.     101.     3.56  1465  27.1   68.2    6.4
 5 1994-05-01 00:00:00  13.0  0.859  148.     101.     4.01  1526  27.6   68.5    6.1
 6 1994-06-01 00:00:00  15.0  0.846  148.     101.     4.25  1409  26.7   69.0    6.1
 7 1994-07-01 00:00:00  11.1  0.818  148.     101.     4.26  1439  27.8   69.1    6.1
 8 1994-08-01 00:00:00  12.0  0.818  149      101.     4.47  1450  28.8   69.5    6  
 9 1994-09-01 00:00:00  14.3  0.810  149.     101.     4.73  1474  27.9   69.7    5.9
10 1994-10-01 00:00:00  14.6  0.793  149.     101.     4.76  1450  28.9   70.3    5.8
# … with 327 more rows, and 2 more variables: CLI <dbl>, SPYr <dbl>
```

Here is the variable merged newdata :

```
         CLI          SPYr DIS.Close
1  100.52128  0.0000000000  15.53738
2  100.70483 -0.0291642024  15.53738
3  100.83927 -0.0473966064  15.53738
4  100.92260  0.0170457821  15.53738
5  100.95804  0.0159393078  15.53738
6  100.95186 -0.0293319435  15.53738
7  100.91774  0.0391511218  15.53738
8  100.86948  0.0381206253  15.53738
9  100.80795 -0.0311470101  15.53738
10 100.72614  0.0346814791  15.53738
11 100.60322 -0.0398155024  15.53738
12 100.42905 -0.0006857954  15.53738
13 100.19862  0.0418493643  15.53738
```

In fact, for each row of `DATA` there is the first row of `DISclose`and so on for the 2nd, the 3rd... Then my dataset go from x row to x^2 row.

I did some research to fix this problem, and I should match both datasets through `by="matchingIDinbothdataset"` but I do not have matching ID. Is there a solution ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in the variable DATA?

Comment: It's a dataset in excel with all these datas `USDEUR+CPI+CONSCONF+FEDFUNDS+HOUST+UNRATE+INDPRO+VIX+SPY+CLI`.